# Configure managed httpmodule from GAC to work both in Classic and Integrated modes

Tags: iis-8, httpmodule, machine.config, applicationhost

I've developed a custom managed HttpModule (.NET 2), installed it on **GAC** and added it in `Modules` section for IIS 8.5 globally.

For each website with **Integrated mode** this module is visible in it's Modules section as *Inherited* and it works as designed for all .NET 2 and .NET 4 web applications (without manipulating each site's `Web.Config`) .

As for websites in **Classic mode**, it's not there and therefore it's not accessible and working inside classic web application.

I tried editing `applicationHost.config` and `Web.Config` (v2 and v4) in any way but I got no result (It seems `Machine.Config` has no place for it).

How and where can I globally register that same module to handle classic mode without adding dll to bin and/or editing each website's Web.Config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it works now. For future reference:

I edited `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` and got no response because IIS reads config from 64bit framework, so adding module inside `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` solved the problem.

Alternatively for AppPools < .NET 4, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config` must also be edited.

For Integrated mode adding the custom module via IIS GUI to master Modules section is sufficient.

As the result, one custom module installed on GAC is accessible for all .NET 2.0 + websites under IIS, Integrated and Classic, 32bit and 64bit with no need to edit each website's Web.Config separately.

This is useful especially for hostmasters and server administrators to monitor websites' activities (Errors, DDOS attacks, etc) without direct intervention.

Comment: are you sure this works? I don;t see any way to add httpmodules into machine.config file, I have added them to applicationhost.config file but it does not work for classic application pools.

Comment: This was from more than 5 years ago and somehow I managed to make it work at that time, I don't remember details.